# How to ask Safari to automatically enter reader view on SwiftUI macOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, safari, swiftui

Since SFSafariViewController is not available. Clicking a url in macOS app usually opens a new tab in macOS's Safari. I'm using below code in SwiftUI to open a website. But code below does not allow me to ask safari to automatically enter reader view.

**Is there a way to automatically enter reader view on macOS? (Without user tweaking safari setting)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL

    var body: some View {
        Button("Visit Apple") {
            openURL(URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make SFSafariViewController available by wrapping it in a UIViewControllerRepresentable or a NSViewControllerRepresentable depending on your needs.

Comment: @Andrew unfortunately it doesn’t work. Document says: “In Mac apps built with Mac Catalyst, SFSafariViewController launches the default web browser instead of displaying a modal window.“ In this case, the configuration, even when set to auto enter reader view, does not work on mac’s safari.